# Pandas, adding column values of one dataframe to another by iterrows

Tags: python, string, pandas

The issue:

I have two dataframes (MASSIVE number of items):

```
df1 = 0    1    2
      str  str  str
      str  str  str
      ...


df2 = A    B    C    D
      str  str  str  str
      str  str  str  str
      ...
```

What I want to do is to compare if the strings of one column to the columns of the second dataframe:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if df.iloc[index][0] in df2['A'].tolist(): #I'm converting to list because it seems like it can't look into the column as an object
```

If so, what I would like to do is to pick the `df2['B']` value in the same row of the matching string, and eventually put it into a new column in `df1`, where I would have something like:

```
df1 = 0    1    2    B
      str  str  str  str
      str  str  str  nan
      str  str  str  nan
      str  str  str  str
```

I feel like `iterrows()` is not the best method to do so, but I'm not enough skilled to find a better solution.

Thank you.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more with an example, rather than just using the "str" placeholder?

Comment: Providing samples, e.g. **df1.head().to_dict()** would help a lot to visualize the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also assuming I understood your question correctly:

you can use the .isin() method:

```
mask = df2['your_column'].isin(df1['your_other_column'])
df1.loc[mask,'new_column']  = df2.loc[mask,'your_column']
```

please note that the dataframes have to be the same size for this method to work....

something else I just thought of is using a dictionary and apply. I'm assuming you have unique values in the compare column.

```
mask = df2['compare_column'].isin(df1['compare_column'])
dictionary = dict(df2[['compare_column','new_column']][mask].values)
df1['B'] = df1.apply(lambda x: dictionary[x['compare_column']], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you should be able to do the following. The first statement computes a temporary column 'temp' that is True if it can find the value of df1 in df2['A']. The second line looks up this value in df2['B'] if temp is True, otherwise it returns np.NaN:

```
for col in df1.columns:
    df1['temp'] = df1[col].isin(df2['A'].unique())
    df1[col] = df1[[col,'temp']].apply(lambda x: df2['B'].get_value(df2[df2['A'] == x[col]].index[0]]) if x['temp'] else np.NaN, axis=1)
```